# How to interface ffmpeg with snap image

Tags: snap, ffmpeg, interface

I have been trying to find a way to interface OpenToonz snap image with the ffmpeg on my machine. I can't find a way to do it. Please if you can tell me a way to go about this.

Comment: What's a "snap image"?

Comment: a snap image is essentially a program for Linux inside a container so its not technically part of your system. https://snapcraft.io has more information on what a snap program is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution I found on my own was downloading a static build of ffmpeg and then linking ffmpeg from with in the snap Opentoonz settings since the snap image interfaces the home directory with Opentoons the static build of ffmpeg has to be located in a sub directory of /home/. Another work around is to build openToonz from source and install avoiding snap all together.